# Is putting const before and after a function header equivalent?

Tags: c++, c++11

While reading some code, I didn't understand the meaning of the `const` modifier. For example, are the following two lines equivalent?

```cpp
void output() const;
const void output();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: It is `c++` don't spam `c` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any case
`const T function(ARGS ...)` means that the function returns `const T` object.

For `T function(ARGS ...) const` things are different. First, you can't have this kind of function wherever you want. This function must be only as a `non-static` member function of `user-defined type` (AKA `struct` or `class`).

```
class A
{
  T foo() const; // const function
  const T foo1() const; // wanted to show that you can use both together.
  static const T foo2(); // this is another option
  static T foo3() const; // error: static function cant be const
  static const T foo4() const; // error: the same as above

}
```

Non-static `const` member functions promise, that the object you call the function on, can't be changed.

From the above example

```
An a;
// here you can call any function on the object a that compiles
const A b;
// here you can call only the functions (for non-static ones) that have the `const` modifier
```

Also, note, that if you try a member variable in the `const` function, you will get a compiler error:

```
class B
{
  int var;
  void foo() const {var = 1;} // error: can't modify value
  void foo1() {var = 1;} // alright
}
```

To make it possible to modify a variable in the `const function`, you should declare the variable as a `mutable` one.

```
class C
{
  mutable int var1;
  void foo() {var1 = 1;} // OK
  void bar() const {var1 = 1;} // Also OK
}
```

This might seem to be useless, but the use case is some kind of counters, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In `void output() const`, `const` means that you "promise" the compiler not to modify the `member data` of the class using that `output()` function. Which means `output()` will only be used as a `read-only` function.

`const void output()` means that the function `return` type will be `const`ant.